# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, console-application, xp-cmdshell, datasetextensions

I have a C# Console Application that uses System.Data.DataSetExtensions that I can run smoothly on the client's server through the command line. The only thing I did was to copy the bin/Release directory contents to a specific directory on the server and run the app through the cmd.

Now, I want to run the same app through an SQL SERVER Job. I've tried both the `CmdExec` and `T-SQL` options, the latest using `xp_cmdshell`. I've also tried running the program without the job, just with the `xp_cmdshell` on a new query tab.

I always get this error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Can someone help me to fix this? Why can I run the program through the `cmd` line and not through `Sql Server`?

Thx a lot!

Comment: set that dll's Properties -> Copy local -> True. Then redeploy it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the database server (where SQL Server was installed) has .NET Framework 3.5 installed.

Comment: Thx, indeed I checked the SQL Server .NET version and it was 2.0 . That explains it. I could get it working by now with @Jonesy trick.