# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2014

**Error Description:**

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or
>   one of its dependencies. The file or directory is corrupted and
>   unreadable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070570)'
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>       To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>       Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>       To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The file
>   or directory is corrupted and unreadable. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070570)]
>          System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>          System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +225
>          System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
>   IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +110
>          System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
>   Boolean forIntrospection) +22
>          System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +34
>          System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +48
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The file
>   or directory is corrupted and unreadable. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070570)]
>          System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +729
>          System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +69
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +226
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +73
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +321
>          System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +170
>          System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +734
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The file
>   or directory is corrupted and unreadable. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070570)]
>          System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +525
>          System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +118
>          System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +708

**Scenario :**

This error popped up on the published app on IIS ,but the local copy works fine in the same machine .

**Dev Environment :**

Visual Studio 2017 , MS SQlServer 2014 , Entity Framework Code First .

**Observation:**

Newly published version has this error but previously published versions works fine. Local copy working fine without any issues in the same machine.

**Tried:**

[Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281507/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-datasetextensions-version-3-5-0-0)
[[Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913620/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-datasetextensions][1])

Comment: Can you try to remove temporary asp.net files, from like:
 C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Te mporary ASP.NET (link might be different for you) and try again?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli okay let me check...

Comment: @ErayBalkanli tried .. without no luck...

Comment: Note that your error says Version=4.0.0.0. Have you the same .net version installed on publish machine? Also, if you have more than one project in your solution, check if all of them are targeting the same version of the DLL.

Comment: @RodrigoWerlang thanks for the suggestion. As I have mentioned, development and published machine is same. Also, the local version works fine and all the previous published versions too. Only the latest publish shows this error suddenly after publish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting solution which worked, as it might help somebody.

There was an optional Windows update related to SqlServer pending which I executed solved the issue.

**Reason for the issue:**
And the issue was due to a Malware attack which needed a restoration to a previous working backup which might have corrupted the dll.

As the error message shows the dll was corrupted/damaged which can be confirmed by executing in PowerShell which confirms the error

```
([system.reflection.assembly]::loadfile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll")).FullName
```

Also, note that downloading and replacing the dll with the same version also didn't solve this. Even tried to remove and add reference from Visual Studio IDE which also didn't help.